# hide div when click only out of it

Tags: jquery, html, hide, show

I have this code:

```
<input id="i" type="text" value="value" />
<div id="u" style="border:solid 1px;width:140px;height:100px"></div>
<p>thanks</p>
```

I want to make #u hidden, and show when I click on #i.
and then when I click out of #u it will be hidden.
but if I click on #u nothing happend.
could you please help me.
thanks alot

Comment: Can you post the code you are using to hide and display the div.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#i").focus(function() {
    //When the user clicks on #i then #u is shown
    $("#u").show();
}):

$("#u").blur(function() {
    //When the user clicks out of #u then #u is hidden
    $("#u").hide();
}):
```

Comment: Reason for downvote please? The OP asks when the "i" is focused, as it is an input. Then when lose focus hide "#u"

Comment: you was wrong before i downvoted and then you edited so i removed downvote